# How come I can't remove the blue textarea border in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

In Chrome, there is a blue border around the textarea.

How come I can't remove it?

```
textarea:hover, input:hover, textarea:active, input:active, textarea:focus, input:focus {
        outline:0px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You have write `-webkit-appearance:none;` like this:

```
textarea:hover, 
input:hover, 
textarea:active, 
input:active, 
textarea:focus, 
input:focus,
button:focus,
button:active,
button:hover,
label:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn.active
{
    outline:0px !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You forgot about `select` type to make it complete. But good ;)

Comment: This solution will affect a lot the checkboxes. You could specify the text input types tho, something like `input[type="text"]:hover, ..., input[type="text"]:focus, ...` and so on for all input occurrences.

Comment: I needed only the box shadow for Twitter Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 59):

### Bootstrap 3

If you just want to change the color, change the variable (*recommended*):

#### Less or [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

```
@input-border-focus: red;
```

[variables.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L158)

#### Sass

```
$input-border-focus: red;
```

[variables.sass](https://github.com/alademann/sass-bootstrap/blob/master/sass/_variables.scss#L156)

If you wan't to remove it completely, you'll have to overwrite the [Mixin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L830-L856) that sets the outline.

```
.form-control-focus(@color: @input-border-focus) {}
```

#### CSS

If you are using css overwrite it via:

```
.form-control:focus{
    border-color: #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

[Link to implementation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L830-L856)

Answer (score 45):

I believe that's a shadow. Try this:

```
.box-shadow(none);
```

Or if you're not using LESS:

```
box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: yep that was box-shadow for me but it wasn't showing in firefox console for some reason

Answer (score 18):

try this, I think this will help and your blue border will be removed:

```
outline:none;
```

Comment: nice, this worked for me but i had to remove the box shadow too, still its not blue anymore, cheers.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me

```
.form-control {
box-shadow: none!important;}
```

Comment: Have tried locally. It's also working for BootrapCss 4.x ! thanks

Comment: Working with bootstrap 4. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah this is all that's needed for version 4.

Answer (score 6):

This works 100%.

```
textarea:focus, input[type="text"]:focus,textarea[type="text"]:focus,   input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="datetime"]:focus, input[type="datetime-local"]:focus, input[type="date"]:focus, input[type="month"]:focus, input[type="time"]:focus, input[type="week"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus,  input[type="color"]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus, .form-control:focus {  
border-color: (your color) or none;
box-shadow:(your color) or none;
outline: (your color) or none;}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Bootstrap 4.0**

```
*:focus
{
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: solid 1px red( any color ) !important;
}
```

[visual example](https://prnt.sc/m64514)

Answer (score 4):

Try this change border-color to anything which you want

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**BOOTSTRAP 4**

If you do not want to kill a fly with bazooka by use -webkit-appearance:none; which also kills nice sliderinputs btw and presuming you are working with the bootstrap form css selector "form-control" for your input.

This is the solution:

```
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none!important;
    border-color: #ced4da!important;
}
```

If you want to keep a tiny small blue outline the leave border-color out.

Answer (score 3):

If you are someone, who still face this issue.

Here is the answer, thanks god.

```
.radio-custom input[type=radio]:focus+label::before {
    background-image: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

**You are wondering why others solution doesn't works for you**.

Because the style wasn't actually applied to radio button.

Add this style you will find your answer

```
input[type="text"] {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**label::before** thats where you have to apply your style.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.. All the other solutions didn't quite work for me, but I understood one thing from the other solutions and its that default styles of `textarea` and `label` in combination is responsible for the blue border.

```
textarea, label
{
    outline:0px !important;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

EDIT: I had this issue with [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) textarea. Thats why this solution worked for me. So, if you are using Ant, then use this.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Work out computed styles via an inspector]

For future reference you can work out computed styles via an inspector

Answer (score 1):

Use `outline: transparent;` in order to make the outline appear like it isn't there but still provide accessibility to your forms. `outline: none;` will negatively impact accessibility.

Source: http://outlinenone.com/

Comment: How is having a transparent outline different from having no outline at all in terms of accesibility?

Comment: @AdrianPauly `outline: transparent` is presentational (color) vs displaying absolutely nothing. It gives the appearance that it isn't there but it is. Screen readers don't care about presentation but they do care if something is actually displayed which is why we do things like

    .element-invisible {
      position: absolute !important;
      clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
      clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 1px;
    }

if we want to hide something on a form, like labels, instead of `display:none`. Same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to right click > inspect the element.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and none of the suggestions worked until I did this.

Once I found where the relevant code was in the inspect window, I copied and pasted the relevant code that was causing the :focus to be outlined blue and changed it accordingly.

This is the code that worked in my css

```
.btn.focus, .btn:focus
{
outline: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
input[type=text]:focus{outline: none;}
```

i'm using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this. Works fine on **bootstrap 3.x and 4.0**

```
* {
    outline:0px !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

With this code, you're going to remove outline from all tags and classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea:hover,
input:hover,
textarea:active,
input:active,
textarea:focus,
input:focus
{
    outline: 0px !important;
    border: none!important;
}
```

*use border:none; instead of outline because the focus line is a border not a outline.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still searching. It's neither border or box-shadow. It's actually "outline". So just set `outline: none;` to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.was-validated .form-control:valid,
.was-validated .form-control:invalid {
    background-image: none;
    
    box-shadow: none;
}
.was-validated .form-control:invalid:focus,
.was-validated .form-control:valid {

    box-shadow: none;
}
.form-control:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```