# outline:none is not working on input tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come I can't remove the blue textarea border in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622686/how-come-i-cant-remove-the-blue-textarea-border-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Every search I do to get rid of the highlight on input fields says to use the css:

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

This is not working at all.  I am using the latest version of chrome, firefox, and safari to test this out.

I am also using the Bootstrap css library, I am not sure if this would cause this kind of problem.

The effect I am trying to achieve is a blank line in a simulated console screen.  I have it working and looking perfectly, except for the highlight when the inout field is in focus.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of that is working  Ill add the actual css I have on that element to my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't attach it to the `:focus` pseudo-event.

```
input
{
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Not working Chrome 54

Answer (score 11):

The solution that is working for me

```
input, input:focus{
        position:absolute;
        width:auto;
        bottom:0px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:2px;
        background-color:#000000;
        color:#33FF00;
        border-width: 0px;
        outline:0; /* I have also tried outline:none */
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Specifically the base css that fixes the problem:

```
input, input:focus{
        border-width: 0px;
        outline:0; /* I have also tried outline:none */
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

I had originally forgotten to set the box-shadow to none.

Answer (score 8):

If `input{outline:none;}` is not working, try:

```
input, input:focus{
  outline:0px !important;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

Comment: This helped me on button. Specifically the !important. It even works with none. Turns out it was because bootstrap was overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
input {
    outline:none;
}
```

Works for me on my site.
If it won't work for you try to provide a fiddle.

Comment: What do you mean by provide a fiddle?

Comment: @KayoticSully He means create an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: An example using http://jsfiddle.net/. But now as I think about it it may be not so simple if you're using bootstrap. Nonetheless most probably the best answer your looking for is provided in the link of James Allardice comment to your question.

Comment: Bootstrap is what was causing the issue, specifically the boxshadow.  I had to diable the shadows, now its working perfectly.