# focus: none doesn't work for selectInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to turn focus off for selectInput() in an R Shiny application using CSS.

[image]

Shouldn't the following declaration in the `.selectize-input.focus` selector accomplish this?

`.selectize-input.focus {
  focus: none;
}`

For now, I'm just using this. The box is still focused, but it's clearish instead of blue.

`.selectize-input.focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To remove the blue highlighting around focused `SelectInput`, you can use this style:

```
shinyApp(fluidPage(
            tags$head(
              tags$style(HTML(".selectize-input.focus {
                                  border-color: #cccccc;
                                  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                                  box-shadow: none;
                              }"))
            ),
            selectInput("input1", "input1", c("1","2"),"1")), 
         server=function(input, output){})
```

You will find several answers there : [How come I can't remove the blue textarea border in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622686/how-come-i-cant-remove-the-blue-textarea-border-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: HubertL,

Thank you for the clarification about CSS. Unfortunately, I ran your code and it does not accomplish what I want. The blue highlight is still there when I select an option.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough example. This solved a big issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the selectize stylesheet uses the `.selectize-input.focus` selector istelf. Add the parent element to your selector to overrule the default stylesheet:

```
.selectize-control > .selectize-input.focus {
  border-color: white;
  box-shadow:none;
}
```